# Page 404 not found laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i am trynig to insert data in database when i click submit button it returns 404 not found

here is the controller

```
   function ajouterfrm()
   {
    return view('dashboards.directeur.ajouter');
   }
   
   function add(Request $request)
   {
        $request->input();  
   }
```

and here is the routes

```
Route::get('rapport/ajouter',[DirecteurController::class,'ajouterfrm'])->name('directeur.ajouter');
Route::post('add',[DirecteurController::class,'add'])->name('directeur.add');
```

my html :
here is my html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" style="margin-top: 50px">
            <h4>Ajouter Rapport</h4>
            <hr>
            <form action="add" method="POST">
               <input type="text" name="data_1" required>
               <input type="text" name="data_2" required>
               <!-- others inputs and selects ... -->
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i tried to unname the last route but without any results

any suggestions ?

thanks

Comment: So im guessing the first route ```rapport/ajouter``` works fine?

Comment: yes its working the problem is when i click submit button

Comment: Is the code you provided the entire code? as ```$request->input()``` doesnt really do anything here

Comment: just for testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form should look like this :

```
<form action="{{ route('directeur.add') }}" method="post">
  @csrf // for preventing forgery token attacks otherwise you will get an "419 error"
  <your inputs ...>
<form>
```

bonne chance.

Answer (score 0):

Your add route doesn't do anything at this point, so no view or response is returned for the request.

You need to return something from your controller. Please see:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses

But for now you can try in your add function

```php
return response('test');
```

Comment: i forgot to write the return statement but its still

Comment: `
 function add(Request $req){

      return  $req->input();  
   } 
`

Answer (score 0):

here is my html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" style="margin-top: 50px">

            <h4>Ajouter Rapport</h4>

            <hr>

            <form action="add" method="POST">

            
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Titre</label>
                  <input type="text" name="titre" class="form-control" placeholder="Entrer le titre du rapp">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Description</label>
                    <textarea name="description" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Entrer la description ici...">
                    </textarea> 

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="">Médecin</label>
                      <select class="form-control" name="medecin" id="">
                        <option value="med">Médecin 1</option>
                        <option value="med">Médecin 2</option>
                        <option value="med">Médecin 3</option>
                      </select>


                    </div>
                
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="">Patient</label>
                   <select class="form-control" name="patient" id="">
                     <option value="pat">Patient 1</option>
                     <option value="pat">Patient 2</option>
                     <option value="pat">Patient 3</option>
                   </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Ajouter</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just delete this piece of code, i've added it in your answer . for contacting a user you can directly find his email/contacts on his profile page.